# wicket issue on nested forms when use FileUpload

Tags: java, forms, file-upload, wicket

i wrote a panel in wicket that let me upload a file and it totally works.
but when i place that panel in an other form (`wicket:id="outerForm"`), and upload a file, it throws an exception from (`component id= outerForm`):

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletRequest does not contain multipart content. One possible solution is to explicitly call Form.setMultipart(true), Wicket tries its best to auto-detect multipart forms but there are certain situation where it cannot.`

but for `outerform` I've call `form.setMultipart(true)`

does anyone know how to fix it?
i use wicket 1.4.21

thanks

Comment: Don't you try to submit outer form via AJAX? Also check whether you're really using POST method for submitting of the outer form.

Comment: yes, I submit outer form via AJAX. the problem has been solved. it was my fault. there was an other outer form. it works fine. the only thing you need to write `form.setMultipart(true)` for all forms.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem now. Here is how I fixed:

My outer and inner forms both have setMultipart(true) and it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the enctype, because you're working with upload files, so just do that:

In your form insert "setMultipart()".

For example:

```
public class MyForm extends Form<T>{

  public MyForm(String id){
   super(id);
   setMultiPart(true);
   }

}
```

I think it can help you.